# MariaDB slow query in CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE

Tags: mariadb, query-optimization

I have problem with slow query with index.

Execution time of this query is more than 4 seconds:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `active_users` ENGINE = 'MEMORY' AS(
    SELECT `id`
    FROM  `users`
    WHERE `blocked_at` IS NULL 
    AND   `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
    AND   `users`.`id` NOT IN(11, 22)
);
```

With index:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `index_active_users` (`blocked_at`, `deleted_at`);
```

But query:

```sql
SELECT `id`
FROM  `users`
WHERE `blocked_at` IS NULL 
AND   `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
AND   `users`.`id` NOT IN(11, 22)
```

Has execution time below 100ms.

Without `index_active_users` index time of CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE... query is below 500ms.

Database version:  10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1-log - Debian 10

Users table count: 448 283

Users count from query: 416 085

Table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `blocked_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `index_active_users` (`blocked_at`,`deleted_at`);
```

I have removed `index_active_users` index.

Why create of this index has such meaning for execution time?

Comment: Test 2-query variant, `CREATE TABLE` then `INSERT .. SELECT`, and check the time spent for each separate query.

Comment: 'Execution time of this query is more than 4 seconds:'- is that a one off or over a number  of tries?

Comment: @P.Salmon
Is super steady min 4 seconds on multiple query like 10 queries per second for few hours.

Comment: You lost me..what do you mean by 'multiple query like 10 queries per second for few hours'

Comment: What is your actual question? Why creating a temporary table + an index is slower than not doing that?

Comment: What will you then do with the ids in the Memory table?  It might be faster to `JOIN users ON ... WHERE ...`

Answer (score 0):

tested on 10.4:

```
MariaDB [test]> insert into users select seq, IF(RAND() < 416085/448283, NULL, NOW()), NULL FROM seq_1_to_448283;
Query OK, 448283 rows affected (2.345 sec)
Records: 448283  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `active_users` ENGINE = 'MEMORY' AS(
    ->     SELECT `id`
    ->     FROM  `users`
    ->     WHERE `blocked_at` IS NULL 
    ->     AND   `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
    ->     AND   `users`.`id` NOT IN(11, 22)
    -> );
Query OK, 416035 rows affected (0.464 sec)
Records: 416035  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [(test)]> pager > /dev/null
PAGER set to '> /dev/null'

MariaDB [test]> SELECT `id` FROM  `users` WHERE `blocked_at` IS NULL  AND   `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL  AND   `users`.`id` NOT IN(11, 22);
416035 rows in set (0.287 sec)

MariaDB [(test)]> pager


MariaDB [test]> alter table users drop index index_active_users;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.004 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `active_users_no_index` ENGINE = 'MEMORY' AS(     SELECT `id`     FROM  `users`     WHERE `blocked_at` IS NULL      AND   `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL      AND   `users`
.`id` NOT IN(11, 22) );
Query OK, 416035 rows affected (0.428 sec)
Records: 416035  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

So creating a temporary table with/without and index - no difference.

Why is a `SELECT` statement quicker than a `CREATE TABLE statement`? Its a more complicated, and looking at the performance profile a significant amount of calls to memory allocation occurs.

A more significant question is how did you measure a memory table containing 92% of your data to be quicker, without indexes, than an InnoDB table where its all going to be in the memory buffer pool cache anyway. I suspect it isn't, especially with the `create table engine=memory` overhead.